# How to get the object you just post using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, activiti

What I am doing is create an object with its name defined, and post into a database then find its position immediately and get its id. I realize if I use "get" just after "post" it will get the data before post. How can I update the database before get it? Any suggestion will be helpful, thank you very much!

```
/*controller createCtrl*/
outbox.controller('createCtrl',function($scope,$http,$filter,$window){
    console.log("In create control.");
    $scope.create = function(name){
        var a=$scope.name;
            console.log(a);
        var newmodel={name:a,};

        /*Post new model*/
        var urlpost = restURL+'/service/repository/models?size=50';
        console.log(urlpost);
        $http.post(urlpost,newmodel)
        .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
           console.log(status);
           $scope.model = response.data;
          })
        .error(function(response, status, headers, config){
           console.log(response.error_message);
           $scope.error_message = response.error_message;
          });
        /*get the databese*/
        $http.get(urlpost,reqConfig)
        .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
           console.log(status);
           $scope.models=response.data;
           console.log(response.data);
          console.log(a);
           var w=$filter('filter')(response.data,{name:newmodel.name},true);
           console.log(w);
           var urllink="rootURL+modeler.html?modelId="+w[0].id;
           console.log(urllink);
           $window.open(urllink);
          })
        .error(function(response, status, headers, config){
           console.log(response.error_message);
           $scope.error_message = response.error_message;
          });

    };
});
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 ajax calls in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Don't you just need to make the get request in the success block of the post request?

```
/*Post new model*/
var urlpost = restURL+'/service/repository/models?size=50';
console.log(urlpost);

$http.post(urlpost,newmodel)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        $scope.model = response.data;

        /*get the database here*/
        return $http.get(urlpost, reqConfig);
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        $scope.models = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(a);
        var w=$filter('filter')(response.data,{name:newmodel.name},true);
        console.log(w);
        var urllink="rootURL+modeler.html?modelId="+w[0].id;
        console.log(urllink);
        $window.open(urllink);
    })
    .catch(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.error_message = response.data;
    });
```

Comment: Ahhhh right! Thank you very much!! How could I write this haha!

Comment: Use of `success` and `error` is deprecated, use `then` instead.

Comment: @deek answer is the best solution in your case but I answered you as the way you asked. I didn't fully read your post too.

Answer (score 3):

In your back end, create the new entry followed by a retrieval of the new entry. For the response object, send back that data of the newly retrieved data.

No need for two Ajax requests.

Comment: Appears that the backend is already returning the affected object. Maybe it is not returning as is in database, then something can be broken.

Comment: He might need to use callbacks/promises/etc. to ensure the database data he returns comes after the update. Right now he's have two ajax requests and I presume starting a new database session when 1 of each will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code I post 2 weeks ago is wordy. The $http.post will directly response the object you just create, so the filter can be remove. The better way to still use .success and .error would be:

```
outbox.controller('createCtrl',function($scope,$http,$filter,$window){

    var urlpost = restURL+'/service/repository/models';
    console.log(urlpost);
    $scope.create = function(name){
        if(name==null||name==="undefined"||name==""){
            alert("Model name cannot be empty!")
        }else{
            parent.$.fancybox.close();
            console.log(a);
            var newmodel={name:a,};
            /*Post new model*/
            $http.post(urlpost,newmodel,reqConfig)
            .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                 console.log(status);
                 var modelId=response.id;   
                 var urllink="rootURL+modeler.html?modelId="+modelId;
                 console.log(urllink);
                 $window.open(urllink);

            })
           .error(function(response, status, headers, config){
                 console.log(response.error_message);
                 $scope.error_message = response.error_message;
            });
        }//End of else
        };//End of create function
}); //End of controller
```